# Apache - 2 subdomains, no wildcard SSL certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, subdomain

I have a subdomain that has an SSL certificate that is working nicely. The web address for it is, lets say, like this: `sd1.mydomain.com` (sd1=sub-domain 1). Now I want to add a second subdomain, but it doesn't need to have the certificate encrypting the data. Thus, I want: `sd2.mydomain.com`

I adjusted my `sites-enabled` directory to have two config files, one for each subdomain. The config file for the first, and working, subdomain looks like this (changing actual domain, to "mydomain", obviously):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/sd1.mydomain.com
    SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
    ServerName https://sd1.mydomain.com

    AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /srv/www/cpm/static_media/css/$1
    Alias /static_media/ /srv/www/cpm/static_media/
    Alias /static/admin/ /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
    Alias /favicon.ico "/srv/www/cpm/static_media/img/favicon.ico"


    <Directory /srv/www/cpm/static_media/>
        Options -Indexes
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        deny from 219.0.0.0/8

    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/cpm/django.wsgi

    <Directory /srv/www/cpm>
        Options -Indexes
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        deny from 219.0.0.0/8
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /srv/www/logs/cpm_logs/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /srv/www/logs/cpm_logs/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This site runs a Django webapp that needs to be secure, and it works nicely.

Now I want to set up a second website, a WIKI actually, that does NOT need to be secure, and so I created this config file for `sd2.mydomain.com` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
        ServerName http://sd2.mydomain.com

        DocumentRoot /srv/www/wiki/public_html/

              <Directory />
                  Options FollowSymLinks
                  AllowOverride None
              </Directory>

              <Directory /srv/www/wiki/public_html/>
                  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                  AllowOverride All
                  Order allow,deny
                  allow from all
              </Directory>


              ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

              # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
              # alert, emerg.
              LogLevel warn

              CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

              Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
              <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
                  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                  AllowOverride None
                  Order deny,allow
                  Deny from all
                  Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
              </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I don't have `NameVirtualHost` in there, because I am trying to get each site working on its own, before getting them both running at the same time. (I only activate one at a time)

My problem is that when I open a browser and try to go to `http://sd2.mydomain.com` the site simply will not load and there is nothing in the error log to tell me that something is going wrong. However, if I add all the same `SSL` stuff to my `sd2.mydomain.com` config file, the second site *does* work, but I have to navigate to `https://sd2.mydomain.com` for it to work, and, obviously, the SSL cert fails.

What am I doing wrong here? I feel like all the config stuff is accurate since there are no errors. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So what ports is Apache listening on when you run `netstat -ntlp`?  I notice that don't seem to have a port 80 virtual host in your first example.  Are you sure that you actually have Apache set with `Listen 80`?  Or did that get changed so it is only `Listen 443`?

Comment: Oh, good point. I just added `Listen 80` to my `ports.conf` file in the main `/etc/apache2/` directory (then reloaded/restarted apache). However, same results - can't reach the sight, no error messages in the log file.